# Speed up slow 3 table MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm querying 3 tables in an eCommerce site.

**orders Table:**

```
id
order_number
name
etc...
```

**order_lines table:**

```
id
order_number
sku
quantity
etc.
```

**products Table**

```
id
sku
title
ship_by (INT)
etc.
```

*order_number* links *orders* table to *order_lines* table. *SKU* links *order_lines* table to *products* table.

Notice the *ship_by* column in the products table, this denotes which supplier will ship the item. The query needs to pull orders for a particular supplier. Orders may contain items sold by different suppliers.

This is the query I managed to cobble together:

```
SELECT 
    orders.`order_number`               as `orderId`,
    orders.`shipping`                   as `fPostageCost`,
     FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.`time`)       as `dReceievedDate`,
    (
    CASE orders.`dob`
    WHEN 'COURIER 3 DAY' THEN 'UK_SellersStandardRate'
    WHEN 'COURIER 24 HOUR' THEN 'UK_OtherCourier24'
    ELSE orders.`dob`
    END
    )                       
    ...(plus a number more)

 FROM orders
 INNER JOIN order_lines
 ON   orders.order_number = order_lines.order_number
 WHERE 
       ( 
         (SELECT COUNT(order_lines.sku) 
          FROM order_lines, products 
          WHERE order_lines.sku = products.sku 
          AND products.ship_by = 1 
          AND order_lines.order_number = orders.order_number) > 0 
       )
       AND ( orders.`printed` = 'N' OR orders.`printed` IS NULL )
       AND orders.status = 'Awaiting Despatch'
       AND ( orders.payment_status = 'Success' OR orders.payment_status = 'Paypal Paid' OR orders.payment_status = 'Manual Payment' )
  GROUP BY orders.`order_number`
  ORDER BY orders.order_number ASC
```

It is taking about 7 seconds to execute the query.

If I remove the line 'AND order_lines.order_number = orders.order_number' from the second SELECT query it is executed almost instantly, but without this line it doesn't work as I need it to.

Aside from adding the 'ship_by' column into the order_lines table (which I'd rather not do since I'd have to change a lot of php code), is there any way of modifying this query to speed it up?

The query is being run from outside of PHP so it has to be a pure mysql query.

Here is the EXPLAIN on the query:

```
id  select_type         table        type     possible_keys     key         key_len     ref                                     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             order_lines  ALL      NULL              NULL        NULL        NULL                                    9627    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY             orders       eq_ref   order_idx         order_idx   17          .order_lines.order_number   1       Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  order_lines  ALL      NULL              NULL        NULL        NULL                                    9627    Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  products     ref      sku_2,sku,sku_3   sku_2       63          order_lines.prod_code   11      Using where
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `order_lines` table needs an index on `order_number` at the very least. We would need to see the schema to best choose one. Perhaps a composite index would pick up speed in other areas.

But in choosing index changes, it must be carefully weighed against other queries in your system, and the impact on insert and update speeds.

The goal shouldn't be to make 10% of your app fast, at the expense of the 90.

To show very useful information, publish `show create table tableName` for relevant tablenames. (versus describing it free-hand, like my table has this and that). We need to see the schema for orders, order_lines, products.

The manual page on [Create Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Idk how large the table is on your inline view but if it is large then 
it may help to use a union instead of having to query the view for every record.

Something like.

```
    SELECT L1*
FROM 
(SELECT 
    orders.`order_number`               as `orderId`,
    0                                   AS  SKU_CNT,
    orders.`shipping`                   as `fPostageCost`,
     FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.`time`)       as `dReceievedDate`,
    (
    CASE orders.`dob`
    WHEN 'COURIER 3 DAY' THEN 'UK_SellersStandardRate'
    WHEN 'COURIER 24 HOUR' THEN 'UK_OtherCourier24'
    ELSE orders.`dob`
    END
    )                       
    ...(plus a number more)

 FROM orders
 INNER JOIN order_lines
 ON   orders.order_number = order_lines.order_number
 WHERE  ( orders.`printed` = 'N' OR orders.`printed` IS NULL )
       AND orders.status = 'Awaiting Despatch'
       AND ( orders.payment_status = 'Success' OR orders.payment_status = 'Paypal Paid' OR orders.payment_status = 'Manual Payment' )


 UNION ALL
    Select
    0                       AS  ORDERID,
    COUNT(OL.SKU)           AS  SKU_CNT,
    0                       as `fPostageCost`,
    NULL                    as `dReceievedDate`,
    ...
    FROM ORDER_LINES OL,
         PRODUCTS PR
    WHERE order_lines.sku = products.sku 
          AND products.ship_by = 1 
          AND order_lines.order_number = orders.order_number     
    GROUP BY ORDERID, ORDER_LINES_CNT, fPostageCost`, dReceievedDate`,
)L1
WHERE L1.SKU_CNT > 0
GROUP BY L1.`order_number`
ORDER BY L1.order_number ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the subquery with `exists`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM order_lines ol2 JOIN
                   products p2
                   ON ol2.sku = p.sku AND
                      p2.ship_by = 1 
                      ol.order_number = o.order_number
             ) AND
        . . .
```

But, your snippet of the query is not using `order_lines` in the outer query.  I suspect you can just get rid of it with the aggregation:

```
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM order_lines ol2 JOIN
                   products p2
                   ON ol2.sku = p2.sku AND
                      p2.ship_by = 1 
                      ol.order_number = o.order_number
             ) AND
        . . .
```

This will at least return all the orders information -- and the lack of aggregation may simplify other parts of the query.  If some versions of the query are running fast, then indexes are probably set up reasonable.

Comment: Thanks @drew  & snowsprinkle for your answers. I tried Gordon's suggestion first and based on that I changed the sql to now read:
`SELECT
    o.order_number
    ...etc
 FROM orders o, order_lines ol, products p
WHERE ol.sku = p.sku 
AND p.ship_by = 1 
AND ol.order_number = o.order_number
AND ( o.`printed` = 'N' OR o.`printed` IS NULL )
AND o.status = 'Awaiting Despatch'
AND ( o.payment_status = 'Success' OR o.payment_status = 'Paypal Paid' OR o.payment_status = 'Manual Payment' )
GROUP BY o.`order_number`
ORDER BY o.order_number ASC`

Comment: ...and now the query is done in 0.05 seconds. 140 times faster. Brilliant!

I need to improve my mysql knowledge. Time to hunt down a new book I think. Thanks again.